# Exclude one row from range

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, range

I am working on a `WPF` project which makes an excel. In the excel sheet, I select a range, something like:

```
Range c1 = newSheet.Cells[3, 2];
Range c2 = newSheet.Cells[8, 10];
Range rng = (Range)newSheet.get_Range(c1, c2);
```

and I need to remove, lets say,  line 5 from this range.
How do I exclude a line from a range, based on its index in the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get non-contiguous ranges via the `Range()` method.

In this case, `3, 2` is `B3` and `8, 10` is `J8`.  To get a non-contiguous range excluding row 5:

```
Range rng = newSheet.Range("B3:J4,B6:J8")
```

The only way I can see to do this using cell row/col refs is to select each contiguous range via these and concatenate the resulting addresses, for example:

```
var top = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells[3, 2], sheet.Cells[4, 10]);
var bottom = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells[6, 2], sheet.Cells[8, 10]);
var all = sheet.Range(top.Address + "," + bottom.Address);
```

Comment: Great, is there a way to do it without the letters? because I have very big ranges in my program, and they are not constant and depending on the data I receive

Comment: I've added the only way I can think of.  It may be more useful if you were to provide some more info on the context of the problem, i.e. what are you trying to achieve?  There may be better ways of going about it.